# MikroTik not accepting VPN connections over wifi

Tags: vpn, wifi, l2tp, mikrotik

I'm using MikroTik RouterOS v5.18 x86 on a Dell PC. I have done the following:

- Set Addresses
- Set PPPoE Client & Server
- Set PPTP/L2TP Server
- Make Profiles and Secrets
- SRCNAT MASQUERADE the IPs of PPPoE and PPTP POOL

Now the problem is this:

I have the Setup as shown below.  4 PCs Connected to RouterOS via LAN Switch. 1 PC and Android devices via Tenda W311R+ WIFI Router.  I don't want to give anonymous access to internet via WIFI hence I set it to DHCP Client not PPPoE.

The problem is that when I connect to VPN via the PC or the Android via WIFI through Tenda router, VPN does not connect. It connects over the Ethernet (wired) connection to Tenda.
I have to work with what I have got, so please do not ask me to buy a WIFI Card for the PC as I know it would make it much easier!

PS This is for a Non-Profit Organization, so you get the idea why I cant buy new stuff!

[image]

Comment: Can any one please help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have handled the problem myself luckily.
I added PortForwarding to my router for the PPTP Ports. Now it works seamlessly.
For any one with same problem, please Port Forward the Port 1723 for VPN passthrough.

Regards